# The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time. Only on native?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been using the Facebook iOS SDK for some app I've been working on - 
My app only requires publishing of a photo, and I have no use of any read permissions or basic info.

When logging in using a browser (Simulator) or Fast-App switching (Device) it works fine with just `openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"]...`

But if I would try the same with an iOS6 device with the Native login, it would show the error describe in the title. Even though I have no need for any read access. This problem only occurs in the native login, and not in the Browser-based or Fast-App switching based logins for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out? Was my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon it has something to do with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/):

### Asking for Read & Write Permissions Separately

*You are now required to request read and publish permission separately (and in that order). Most likely, you will request the read permissions for personalization when the app starts and the user first logs in. Later, if appropriate, your app can request publish permissions when it intends to post data to Facebook.*

*You cannot request read and publish permissions simultaneously using iOS6's Facebook support, and if you attempt to, the SDK will take the user through a less-optimal app-switching or web-based authentication flow.*

It seems that they added this in SDK 3.1.

Comment: I guess the "In that order" part is the most important one. Apparently you can't just ask for publish permissions and upload content without asking for read before that.